# 断言 and 言い切る difference

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering what is the difference between 「言い切る」 and 「断言」? To me they mean the same thing: "declare, assert".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When 言い切る and 断言する mean "to say something definitively", they are very similar and safely interchangeable. The two words are used both in formal essays and casual conversations, but as a Sino-Japanese word, maybe the latter tends to be preferred in formal sentences.

言い切る has another meaning, "to say something until the end," "to clearly finish the sentence."

Comment: Yes I meant 言い切る sorry. I edited my post.
Thanks for the answer!